# Reading XML Source From a Link in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis

How can I put a xml link instead of Xml file in xml source in SSIS?

Like http://domain.com/feeds.xml instead of hard Drive source.

I am trying to put Data From a XML source to a local DB Source.

Do I need to save XML every time or I can get the source from a link?

I am using XML Source in SSIS to get a News feed from a link and insert in a SQL Source.

When I save XML in PC it works, but when put direct xml links it says: Cant find file!

Comment: Can you post the code or method you are currently trying and any error messages it is giving you?

Comment: Error messages are usually *text*. Copy and paste the text here. If what you are trying to share cannot be copied as text, link to an image and someone can edit it in for you.

Comment: Maybe the error is correct. Are you sure you're using a valid address? Did you try to copy the url into a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the file for the XML Source off the file system. This is only how SSIS can validate the input file.

So the step to download it is necessary.

There should not be an issue with that as downloading a file is easy, and it is the best security practice.

I suspect this file also needs to be unblocked.

Comment: Can I download XML via SSIS?

Comment: You can only download it using the stock WebServices task (connector). The other possibility is to write some code in C#/VB.net if the file is not exposed via a webservice. Web scrapping is easier done say with Python.